# Weird behavior regarding IIS virtual directory names

Tags: iis-6, virtual-directory

I'm new to using Microsoft IIS 6.0 and I'm encountering this weird behavior regarding virtual directory names. I once created a virtual directory with the following details:

Alias: Y2YY
Application name: Y2YY
Execute permissions: Scripts and Executables
Local path: D:\Y2YY\content

With D:\Y2YY\content containing a valid html file (hello.html). I was able to successfully access the html file through http://Hostname/Y2YY/hello.html.

I deleted this virtual directory. And tried creating again with the same details. However, I can no longer browse to the html page through http://Hostname/Y2YY/hello.html.

Upon further testing of the virtual directory names, I found out I can only access the html file if the virtual directory name does not begin with Y2YY. This means I could not access the html file with the following virtual directory names (Y2YY*):

Y2YY1   Y2YYabc   Y2YY    Y2YYdef

But I can access the html file if the virtual directory is named anything else. Has anyone encountered this? Is there a setting to clear my previously created virtual directory? I have already deleted it but somehow this problem occurs.

Comment: I see upvotes, does that mean you encountered this before?

Comment: where does the root of the site point to?